# How can I add points from a subset in multiples facet_grid in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have a data frame organized as follow:

```
          Date      Period    Input Streamflow
1   1984-01-01 Calibration Observed     4.4176
2   1984-01-02 Calibration Observed     3.4924
3   1984-01-03 Calibration Observed     3.0657
4   1984-01-04 Calibration Observed     2.7506
5   1984-01-05 Calibration Observed     2.5774
6   1984-01-06 Calibration Observed     3.1584
```

This data frame has 2 different periods and 7 Inputs. I have created a facet_grid divided by Period and Input as follow:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Date, y=Streamflow, group=Period))+
  geom_point(data = filter(df, Input == "Observed"), colour="black") +
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(Input)))+
  facet_grid(Input ~ Period,scales = "free_x") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
p
```

I want to create 12 subplots (6 rows and 2 cols), including 6 inputs (from 7). I would like to repeat the last input ("observed") in all subplots. However, when I created the code, it was created a new plot as the image below:

[image: LIne]

Comment: Remove the Input column from that data.frame for that layer: `select(filter(df, Input == "Observed"), -Input)` or `df %>% filter(Input=="Observed") %>% select(-Input)` Otherwise the `facet_grid` will still use it for partitioning.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. p <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x=Date, y=Streamflow, group=Period))+
  geom_point(data = select(filter(df, Input == "Observed"), -Input), colour="black") +
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(Input)))+
  facet_grid(Input ~ Period,scales = "free_x") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
p